# Passing Resource to Processor in Spring Batch

Tags: xml, jaxb, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch application. In my reader I am reading XML files from a path like this:

```
ItemReader<Foo> xmlFileItemReader(){

    Resource[] resources = getResources();
    MultiResourceItemReader<Foo> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    reader.setResources(resources);

    StaxEventItemReader<Foo> xmlFileReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
    xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("Foo");
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Foo.class);
    xmlFileReader.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    reader.setDelegate(xmlFileReader);
    return reader;
}
```

Now, in my processor I want to get the resource details for some processing. I cannot implement `ResourceAware` in `Foo` as I cannot alter it. So, I tried something like this,

```
public class CustomFoo extends Foo implements ResourceAware{

@XmlTransient
private Resource resource;

@Override
public void setResource(Resource resource) {
    this.resource = resource;

}
```

}

And I modified my reader like this,

```
ItemReader<CustomFoo> xmlFileItemReader(){

Resource[] resources = getResources();
MultiResourceItemReader<CustomFoo> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
reader.setResources(resources);

StaxEventItemReader<CustomFoo> xmlFileReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("Foo");
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(CustomFoo.class);
xmlFileReader.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
reader.setDelegate(xmlFileReader);
return reader;
```

}

My processor looks like this,

```
public class FooProcessor implements ItemProcessor<CustomFoo, Bar>{

@Override
public Bar process(CustomFoo item) throws Exception {
    //process
}
```

}

It did not work. It threw a `ClassCastException` as it was still been unmarshalled to a `Foo` object.

I also tried using `XmlAdapter`. It did not work either.

All I want is to pass the `Resource` to my processor. Please Help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MultiResourceItemReader` [stores](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemReader.java#L203-L213) the index of the current resource in the execution context (with the key: `resourceIndex`). This means if your `ItemProcessor` gets access to the execution context, you are done.

Now in order to get access to the execution context from the item processor, you can:

- use a `@BeforeStep` method and store a handle to the step execution context as explained in the section [Passing Data to Future Steps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps)
- make your `ItemProcessor` implement the [`ItemStream`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemStream.html) interface

I have seen people injecting the `MultiResourceItemReader` in the processor and call the `MultiResourceItemReader#getCurrentResource` inside the processor, but I would not recommend this approach because it couples your processor to the reader.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately it isn't working. I implemented `ItemStream` and used the `@BeforeStep` just as it is in the link that you have shared. The `ExecutionContext` map is always empty.

Comment: I created a sample app here: https://github.com/benas/sandbox/tree/master/so52980807. It shows the resource from which the currently processed item is coming. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Thank you for this. I will try this out. Meanwhile I tried creating a bean for `MultiResourceItemReader` and used it in my `Reader`. Then in my `Processor`, using `ApplicationContext` I retrieved the `MultiResourceItemReader` and got the `Resource` by using the `getCurrentResource` method. It did work. Is that a decent way of doing it?

Comment: As said in the answer, that would work, but will couple the processor to the reader.

Comment: I did try your sample. The line `executionContext.getInt("MultiResourceItemReader.resourceIndex")` return -1 for the first file instead of 0 and it returns 0 for the second file. Any idea why? Or is that how it behaves? Then we have to do a +1 each time.

Comment: The method "ItemStream#update" (where the execution context is stored in the database) is called *after* each chunk. So for the first chunk, the resource index is still to its initial value (-1) and this is what is it seen by the processor. That's why, for the first chunk, we know that items are coming from the resource with index 0 (-1 + 1).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the explanation!